# ExceptionNotifier:Module Migration error at rails production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i do

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

it gives me

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `block in build'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `each'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `inject'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/actionpack-3.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `app'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/ntf-25/hardik/ana/soqueen/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ntf-25/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@shopqi/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this kind of error, What configuration i add to solve this?

My config/environment.rb :-

```
# Load the rails application
```

require File.expand_path('../application', **FILE**)

## Initialize the rails application

Demo::Application.initialize!

There is nothing in enviornment.rb , why this error comes?
 I also add gem for ExceptionNotifier after this error comes , but nothing happend.

Comment: please try find in project `ExceptionNotifier:Module` and post code.

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate a module???????

Comment: Could you show us `config/environment.rb` file?

Comment: There is no ExceptionNotifier:Module in my project  & my enviornment.rb is      # Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Demo::Application.initialize!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer ,  use the gem 'exception_notification' with latest version & configure production.rb according to situation.

In my case i also have to update middleware.rb under intializers.

Answer (score 1):

You also try with

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: As i told previously that it will be solved by gem, but your interest for the question is appreciated.